# Nested double-quotes in Bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell

When I writing bash scripts, I found below statements valid and work as expected:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
fn="file name"
LF='
'
fnc="$LF$(cat "$fn")"
echo "$fnc"
```

But there is a pair of unattended nested quotes in `fnc="$LF$(cat "$fn")"`. Is this a feature, or luck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a feature all POSIX shells have, briefly described in [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) as below.

> The input characters within the quoted string that are also enclosed between `$(` and the matching `)` shall not be affected by the double-quotes[.]

Which means, in this particular case, if you unquote `"$fn"` inside the command subtitution, it will be subjected to word splitting regardless, and `cat` will receive two arguments (`file` and `name`) instead of one (`file name`). Whether `$(cat $fn)` is between double-quotes or not does not affect how `$fn` is expanded.